# How can I change the data usage cycle day for Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, data-monitoring

Changing the starting day for Mobile data was already non-obvious as [shown in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56839/17994).

Now, how can I change the day of month for Wi-Fi usage as well? Currently, I have the following cycles cycles:

- Jun 6 - Jul 4
- May 9 - Jun 6
- Apr 11 - May 9
- Mar 14 - Apr 11

I would like to change these to:

- Jul 1 - Jul 4
- Jun 1 - Jun 30
- Etc.

How can I do that? I am running Android 4.2.2, Cyanogenmod 10.1 from git. This is a longstanding issue that I experienced with ICS too.

Comment: This is not possible now because these limits can only be changed if the connection has a data quota set (such as for Mobile). Wi-Fi connections do not have such a policy set. For technical details, see the `src/com/android/settings/DataUsageSummary.java` file.

Comment: Was looking for how to set the mobile data cycle start date so thanks for that. Might be worth adding that as a separate question and supplying your own answer. I'd+1 that.

Comment: @pelms done, it also appears that 4.3 is still affected...

Comment: On the Android data usage screen WIFI cycle is 4 weeks versus Mobile which is calendar months (I am looking at a Samsung S4  AOS 5.0.1). Is that the same behavior on Cyanogenmod?
I think OP would be trying to compare calendar months Mobile vs WIFI usage,. Telcos typically bill by calendar months.

Comment: @ScottR Yes, CM also shows Wi-Fi usage per four months, this was also still the case with CM 13.0.

Comment: Drop down selections are 3 cycles for Mobile and four cycles for WIFI. @Lekensteyn did you mean a cycle for WIFI is 4 weeks?

Comment: @ScottR yes, four weeks, not four months :p

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a stock app to do this. I have tried using the stock app to do data managing and it's really not that great. [My Data Manager - Data Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) is a great app that will do fine for your situation. It is free of course, so nothing to lose.

Here is their [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5U_9BCJeDQ4) if you want to just check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a profile management app like [SwiP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.fhhgb.mc.swip), [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or [Condi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.co.kix.minitasker)? These should give you more control over your Wifi schedule.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer that the OP wants... these are automation apps, which *might* be useful if OP asked how to manage WiFi data usage; but he didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Change your phone's date to the the start of the next month and restart your phone 
It should show 
1 - 31 march
1 - 30 april
1 - 31 may
Etc