# How can I change the data usage cycle for Mobile data?

Tags: settings, data-monitoring, mobile-data

The mobile data cycle (*Settings* -> *Data usage*) looks quite arbitrary. Since I have changed my data plan, now the new cycle *should* start at the first day of the month instead of the 6th.

How can I change the begin of a data cycle? I cannot seem to find some edit button, though I vaguely remember seeing it at the *Data usage cycle* menu.

Affected versions: Android 4.0, 4.2.2, 4.3.1.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Changing the starting day for Mobile data is indeed non-obvious. You need to enable the mobile data connection (2G/3G) before the options are available:

TURN OFF WIFI First.

1. Enable *Mobile data*.
2. Exit the *Data usage* settings app.
3. Tap the spinner below the *Set mobile data limit* checkbox.
4. Tap *Change cycle...*.
5. Change *Date of each month* (I prefer the first day of the month, `1`)
6. Hit *Set*.
7. Undo *Mobile data* if necessary (e.g. if on Wi-Fi).

Comment: The option _Change cycle_ may appear after selecting the _set mobile data limit_ in the dropdown with dates.

Comment: The cycle length changing feature is in roadmap
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23676

Comment: Even in Android 6.0, you have to turn on mobile data before you see the option to change the cycle.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, What Android version is this? Re "spinner below the Set mobile data limit checkbox"; Meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier It probably applied to Android 4.x (see question). The "spinner" referred to a "drop down" menu where you could select the time range (and the *Change cycle* option). With Android 8.1 (Pixel 2), there is a *Billing cycle* option within the *Data usage* menu (which is visible, independent of whether mobile data is enabled or not).

Answer (score 5):

For me (CM 12.1), it is still confusing. You have to go under `Settings`, `Data Usage` and then:

1. make sure that both `Data connection` and `Set mobile data limit` toggles are  `ON`
2. below them, there is range of dates dropdown, which you can choose to see data usage of previous months. Click on it, and you will get a list of previous periods.
3. now, you have to scroll all the way down through all periods (mine seems to go back all the way down to January 1970 !!!) - below the last one there will be `Change cycle...` option. Click it, and it will allow to change starting date.

Answer (score 0):

I ' ve got it
- Go to Settings -> Data Usage
-> Tap Mobile and them, on the 3 dots at upper corner, chose Disable all appls.
-> Tap WLAN and do the same, disable all appls
-> Restart phone
-> After entering your PW (if any) a display is shown warning about your data usage limit, saying it is paused. them gives you 2 options RESUME or OK
-> Tap RESUME . That's it ! you are back on the road to setup a new cycle.