# Unable to change mobile data cycle date on huawei p9 lite with android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, mobile-data, data-monitoring

My old phone had an option to change the mobile data cycle date. As you can see in the image below the option is gone. Does anyone know where I can find it in this "new and improved" version of android??

and yes I have seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56838/how-can-i-change-the-data-usage-cycle-for-mobile-data?rq=1) but it has changed since this update and it no longer works

[image]
[image]

<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Huawei phones don’t seem to have that feature, which may be due to certain manufacturer's reasons. Its skinned UI (EMUI) provides the feature in a slightly different place.

> If you go to your data management screen, you will find that it does
>   not offer that feature at all. Instead, it shows you your daily usage,
>   and that is about it.

This similar feature is found in **data traffic management**.

Depending on your EMUI version, follow this proceedure:

Go to Settings (All) → Data traffic management → Package settings (or gear icon in later EMUI versions). You should get a screen looking like this:

[image]

> *Here you actually get the Android Data Traffic manager, but a super version of it. You can set daily limits, start the day of the month
>   for your package, disable data if you go over limit to save you money,
>   and set various limits and reminders*

---

Since the feature is somewhat hidden, another probable workaround is installing a 3rd party open source tool [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en)(No root required).

> - Under activities select all activities.
> - Select Settings
> - Search for data usage

Here you will find the options you need to change the mobile data cycle date similar to  what you do in stock versions.

---

Another workaround is installing an altogether data manager application, that takes over the default monitoring of data, cycles etc.

From experience of many users you can search the appropriate one from Playstore e.g ( [My Data manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en), [3G watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog) etc) which are also very flexible when it comes to changing data cycles, limits, reminders and so forth.

**Acknowledgements**

1. [How to: Enabling data limits on your Huawei or Honor smarphone (EMUI 3.1)](https://www.oxgadgets.com/2015/10/how-to-enabling-data-limits-on-your-huawei-or-honor-smarphone-emui-3-1.html)
2. [Change mobile data cycle date](https://forum.xda-developers.com/huawei-p9lite/help/change-mobile-data-cycle-date-t3478646)

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Unfortunately I don't get the data traffic management option. 
I'm not going to install a 3th party app. I'll write something myself to change the "monthly limit" to whatever I have left and reset it once my data is reset. 
should be doable in 15-20 minutes in tasker but I would have liked to not have to resort to that....
Btw: my EMUI version is 5.0.1

Comment: I was also thinking something along the lines of Tasker but I'm short of time....oh but wait isn't Tasker also a 3rd party app?

Comment: Yeah, true. Tasker is a 3th party app but I'm already running it. Your answer is quite good so I'll award the 50 points.

Comment: Thanks for bounty, If I get more time I will try to update the answer with tasker method, im sure there is already a skeleton of the project on reddit, will check the link.

Comment: I made it with the AutoInput tasker plugin and I've set the beginning of the month as the activator. it will briefly activate my screen and set the "data used this month" to the data I used from the 14th onward in the previous month.
On the 14th of the month tasker will reset the "data used this month"

Comment: That's good news indeed, thanks for update and I'm glad you resolved the issue, in any case you may wish to post the answer and self-accept to help users