# No way to clear the Monthly Data Limit on Huawei Mate 10 Lite, Android 7.0, EMUI 5.1

Tags: huawei, emui

So, I'm in my 3rd month of ownership of my first (**and last**) Huawei smartphone and I have discovered yet another strange family of issues.

I have a 20GB monthly data limit from work so I rarely check my data usage. But I had a few extra charges on my last bill so I decided to check it out. (First time on this phone)

The first shock was that there was no Sum of the usage, just a graph with the daily peaks and that's it. So if it was say the 30th, then you would have to add-up 30 days worth of data to find out how much you have left. What a joke:

[image: screenshot]

Anyway, so I figure that I should add a data limit and maybe that will Sum-up my usage. So I tap on the `gear` icon on the top right, then on `Monthly Data Limit` and enter **18GB**. Voila, my total appeared:

[image: screenshot]

From here on, the story gets even stranger.

I tapped on the pencil icon and for some strange, inexplicable reason, you can actually edit your usage. What exactly is the point of that??? So I enter a number and tap on OK to see what happens, and now the Used total becomes whatever amount I entered:

[image: screenshot]

So I decided to revert to the ACTUAL total usage and I was confronted with yet another trademarked Huawei irritation. You cannot clear your own usage, you have to enter something in that box, otherwise `Save` stays disabled:

[image: screenshote]

So as a last resort I thought that I should clear my data limit and be done with all this mess. Sadly I discovered that there is no way of doing that. It seems that once you enable the data limit, you're stuck with one. You can only change the number of `MBs` or `GBs` and again like above, you **have** to enter something in that box otherwise `OK` is disabled:

[image: screenshot]

I tried `Network settings reset` but all that does is **delete** your stored Wi-Fi networks (thanks Huawei) and Bluetooth devices (thanks again !)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to enter a zero ("0") into those fields? If that doesn't work, then an "imaginary limit" of e.g. 200G? And simply put back the original number of your usage (and no, I have no idea why one should edit that)?

Comment: @Izzy - that was the 1st thing I tried. Alas, 0 actually means 0. It effectively disables Mobile data right away. Also, you cannot reset the actual data usage, either

Comment: OK, so set 500G for the limit. And what do you mean you cannot reset data usage? According to your question text you did exactly that (from 1G to 111M).

Comment: Once you've typed your own total. There's no going back to the actual total.

Comment: See if [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191183/209414) works:

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I see lots of complaints here but I'm not sure what the actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear "phone manager"  app data, it will return limit to "not set"
Works on all huawei phones.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, however it does not only delete the usage settings. That's not your fault though :)

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the Phone Manager's cache and it will go bat to 'not set' if you don't want to clear its data, Setting → Apps and Notifications → Phone Manager → Storage → Clear Cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the settings app. Find Settings app in the apps list and clear data.
To check what’s using your data, go to data usage ranking.
It doesn’t let you see a total unless you set a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings → apps and notifications → phone manager → storage → clear data

After clear data it will go back to 'not set'

Answer (score 0):

On my P20 Pro it was "Optimizer" instead of Phone Manager.

Settings -> Apps -> Optimizer -> Storage -> Clear Cache

Answer (score 0):

How to reset back Monthly Data Limit to "Not set"
1st Optimizer from the home screen, Optimize it
2nd Go to Settings -> Apps -> Optimizer -> Storage -> Clear Cache & Clear Data, then restart the mobile